# 近似・平滑化曲線・3次スプライン補完のx=〇のときのyの値

Tags: python

以下のコードで3次スプライン補完のグラフを書きました．そこでx=3のときのyの値を表示させるにはどのようなコードを書けばいいかまったくわかりません．ご教授お願いします．

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=np.array([0, 6, 11 , 20, 30, 40])  #測定時間
y=np.array([92, 105, 114 , 125, 148, 141])  #血糖値データ


f_line = interp1d(x, y)
f_CS = interp1d(x, y, kind='cubic')

#for plot
xnew =np.linspace(0, 40, num=50)
plt.plot(x, y, 'o')
plt.plot(xnew, f_CS(xnew), '-')

plt.legend(['Raw data','Lagrange', 'Cubic spline'], loc='best')
plt.show()

print(y)
```

Comment: [interp1d.__call__](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.__call__.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d.__call__) を使えば良いでしょう。

Comment: このプログラム的に言えば`f_CS(3)`で取得出来るような気がしますが。@metropolis さんの言っていることもそれなのでは？

Comment: ｢x=3のときのyの値を表示｣とはグラフに描画するという意味でしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

例えば以下のようにすれば出来るでしょう。
表示関連の部分だけ抜粋してみました。

```
#for plot
xnew =np.linspace(0, 40, num=50)
plt.plot(x, y, 'o')
plt.plot(xnew, f_CS(xnew), '-')
plt.plot(3.0, f_CS(3.0), 'X')   #### X =  3 の時の値をグラフ上にプロット
plt.plot(15.0, f_CS(15.0), '*') #### ついでに X = 15 の時の値をグラフ上にプロット

#### legend に追加した点の内容を追記
plt.legend(['Raw data','Lagrange', f'X=3, Y={f_CS(3.0):.2f}', f'X=15, Y={f_CS(15.0):.2f}'], loc='best')
plt.show()

print('X =  3 の時の Yの値 = ', str(f_CS(3.0)))  #### 値をテキストで表示、必要なら何かに代入して使う
print('X = 15 の時の Yの値 = ', str(f_CS(15.0)))
```

グラフはこんな結果になります。
[image: graph]